# Deploy Problem (it is not setting the cookie)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cookies, axios

I am sending requests from the client to my Express.js server using Axios.

the problem is that the cookies are not being set, and that I am using the "withCredentials: true"

server side:

```
app.use(cors({
    origin: "https://butterflix.vercel.app",
    credentials: true,
  }));

app.use(express.json());

app.use(cookieParser());
```

client side:

```
export const sendLoginRequest = createAsyncThunk("login", ({email, password}) => {
    return axios.post("https://butterflix.onrender.com/api/users/login", {
        email: email.value,
        password: password.value,
      }, { withCredentials: true, credentials: 'include' })
      .then(() => {
        return axios.get("https://butterflix.onrender.com/api/users/me", { withCredentials: true, credentials: 'include' })
            .then(res => res.data)
      })
})
```

Comment: Browsers visiting a page on `*.vercel.app` may refuse to send a cookie to `*.onrender.com`, because this counts as a third-party cookie. (May depend on browser settings.)

Comment: and what do i have to do to fix it? do you know?

Comment: i have "Allow all cookies" option in chrome, can be a problem of my code ?